# Probability two numbers add such that the number of digits increase by at least 1?

Tags: probability, real-numbers

Take two number $n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $n_1$ is known but $n_2$ is not, what is the probability that,
$$
\frac{n_1}{10} \leq \frac{n_1 + n_2}{10}
$$
Given that $p_1 < n_1, n_2 < p_2$ where $p_1, p_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$ and are the boundaries of a range proof. Furthermore expanding it to base $b$ such that,
$$
\frac{n_1}{b} \leq \frac{n_1 + n_2}{b}
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "hold a new slot"? I'm struggling to understand the question.

Comment: As in take 4+n, what's the probability that this becomes greater than or equal to 10, (hence hold two slots, I'm not sure what to call it).

Comment: So what is the probability that the number of digits increases by at least one given $n_1$ and knowing the $n_2$ is being chosen from between $p_1$ and $p_2$?

Comment: Yes exactly I'll edit the question now.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easy to solve by finding the number $n_2'$ such that $$n_1+ n_2' = 10^{\lceil \log_{10} n_1 \rceil}?$$ Then, once you have this, simply get the probability (assuming a equal probability of choosing any number) by $$\frac{p_2 - n_2'}{p_2 - p_1}$$ and then limit the range to $[0,1]$ (You would only have to do this if $n_2' < p_1$ or $n_2' > p_2$). Please correct me if I am misunderstanding something

Comment: You write $n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, but do you really mean that the numbers are reals or do they have to be whole positive numbers? Also, your inequalities don't really make sense, because as written they hold true for any $n_2 \ge 0$ and that surely is not what you mean. You don't want division by $10$ or by $b$, but it seems you mean the length of the number when written in base $10$ or base $b$. Is that correct? If the numbers are allowed to be non-integer reals, what do you consider to be the length of the number?

Comment: @Alerra. This is for a range proof, so I need to know before the computation what the probability is.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis If it's easier it could be done in $\mathbb{Z}$, I'll edit it.

Comment: But in order to find the probability don't you need to know what number $n_2'$ would increase the number of digits by 1?

Comment: That probability will be in relation to $p_2$ as well as $n_1$?

Comment: It will depend on $n_1$, $p_1$ and $p_2$. Think about it. If $n_1$ is close to a number that switches digits (i.e $n_1 = 9$), then the probability will be greater. Likewise, as $p_1$ gets larger, the probability of choosing a number big enough to add an extra digit goes up.

Comment: Yes, exactly, but I have no idea where to start with the calculations (Writing a Math IA as a high school student for IB and this problem keeps popping up).

Comment: Do we know what $n_1$ is beforehand? Above, I assumed we did know $n_1$, but if we don't, I could write an answer that accounts for this.

Comment: Yes we do, we just do not know $n_2$, $p_1$ and $p_2$ are known for the verifier.

Comment: Alright, I'll write a more in-depth answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that we know $n_1$, we want to first find the smallest number $n_2'$ such that the number of digits in $n_1 + n_2'$ has at least one more digit than $n_1$. In other words and shown above in my comment, we want to find $n_2'$ satisfying:
$$
n_1 + n_2' = 10^{\lceil \log_{10} n_1\rceil}
$$
The second term may look complicated, but all it does is find the smallest power of 10 greater than $n_1$. So, if $n_1 = 9$, then $10^{\lceil \log_{10} 9 \rceil} = 10$. Thus, we can solve for $n_2'$ as:
$$
n_2' = 10^{\lceil \log_{10} n_1\rceil} - n_1
$$
Now, once we have this, we know that all values $\geq n_2'$ will increase the number of digits by 1, otherwise it won't. The range of choices we have for $n_2$ is $p_2 - p_1$, and the range of "valid" choices (ones that will increase the number of digits by at least one) will be $p_2 - n_2'$. Thus, the overall probability given $n_1$ is 
$$
P(\text{extra digit} | n_1) = \frac{p_2 - n_2'}{p_2 - p_1}
$$ 
Note that if this number is negative, then the probability is really 0, and if it is greater than 1, then the probability is really 1. These cases occur when $n_2'$ is outside the bounds $[p_1,p_2]$.

Hope this was understandable, leave a question if you have one.

Comment: Thank you so much, this answer was both clear and concise. I was wondering if I could include this as part of my IA? I'm not sure how to reference you however. Also, just one more step, since we only know $n'_2 = 10^{\log_b(n_1)} - n_1$ hence, $P(\text{extra digit}|n_1) = \frac{p_2 + n_1 - \log_b(n_1)}{p_2 - p_1}$.

Comment: That's fine, if you want to reference me, go for it, if you don't, I really won't care that much. Also, you made a slight inaccuracy in the last step. If you group it all together it becomes $$ P(\text{extra digit} | n_1) = \frac{p_2 + n_1 + b^{\lceil \log_b n_1 \rceil}}{p_2 - p_1}$$ Note that I substituted $b$ in where I had 10 before to make it be any base you want.

Comment: Yeah sorry using comments makes it really hard to see the equation before you add it and I couldn't edit it a second time...

Comment: Yea no worries. Glad I could help